# Where are the report queries and layouts stored in Oracle Apex 3.2?

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

Since we use the reports as letters they change frequently.
Whe have 19 organisations that use their own letters.

We do not want grant them developers rights for uploading their letters so for now we have to do this for them. Since this takes a lot of our time we want to create a user screen in Apex where they can upload these letters as an application user.

But where are the report layout and queries stored in the DB?

We still use version 3.2

Comment: Usually, if you have users upload things to an Apex application you store these things in a table you create for that purpose. Then, you have your Apex application query that table and do something with the results. 
It's unclear what do you mean by "letters" and what you want to do with it later.

Comment: Hi Rene, these are letters you print and send by the postals. They are created with bi-publisher. But do you know where they are stored?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't advisable to edit the Apex workspace directly to modify objects.

Alternatively Apex allows you to run a report against a query returned by a function if you select the report type as `PL/SQL Function Returning SQL Query as the report implementation type`,[Dynamic Report Example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/dynamic-report-092026.html#DYN_REPORT).

In this case as suggested by Rene you could store the query for the users report in a table, and through a package or function return this to the report at runtime. Users could have permissions to update the value for the SQL but need not be developers.

How to alter the layout when printing the report would depend on your print/report solution and we'd need more detail to help you with that.

Comment: Oke, we use rtf files with BI-publisher. These are letters that will be printed and send by postals.

they are now stored as shared components layout and the query also as shared component.

The query's are pre defined for the users and they may not change them. The layout of the template however is their choice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply on such an ancient question, but this appeared in my Google search, so I might as well help some other searchers...the tables where the "Report Query" and "Report Layout" are stored are:

```
APEX_XXXXXXX.WWV_FLOW_REPORT_LAYOUTS 

APEX_XXXXXXX.WWV_FLOW_SHARED_QUERIES
```